# Recent updates - Story like snapchat

Tags: ios, swift, parse-platform

I have a story like Snapchat, where you see the oldest first. But how can I save where the user saw the last story, so the user can continue to watch from where he left off, instead of watching the whole story from the start again?

This is my query code:

```
func queryStory(){
        let query = PFQuery(className: "myClassStory")
        query.whereKey("isPending", equalTo: false)
        query.limit = 1000
        query.orderByDescending("createdAt")
        
        query.findObjectsInBackgroundWithBlock { (posts: [PFObject]?, error: NSError?) -> Void in
            if (error == nil){
                // Success fetching objects
                
                for post in posts! {
                    
                    if let imagefile = post["userFile"] as? PFFile {
                        self.userFile.append(post["userFile"] as! PFFile)
                        self.objID.append(post.objectId!)
                        self.createdAt.append(post.createdAt!)
                    }
                }
                print("Done!")
            }
            else{
                print(error)
            }
        }
    }
```

To detect the current image in the story, I use `self.objID`.

Answer (score 0):

You could use NSUserDefaults for this. Either save the ID number of the post that they have reached, or an array that stores a value of "seen" or "unseen" for each post.

Comment: But if I want them to be able to continue to watch from where they left off, how would I make it start from the ID number of the post that they have reached?

Comment: In `viewDidLoad()`, you can do `self.tableView.scrollToRowAtIndexPath(NSIndexPath(forRow: lastSeenRow, inSection: 0), atScrollPosition: .Top, animated: true)` where you'll have to find the value `lastSeenRow` from your data source by finding the position of the post that has the ID you saved

Comment: I was going to suggest changing your `for post in posts` to iterate from the last post seen to the end, but Jeremy's solution is better (IMO) because it would give the option to scroll back up to earlier posts - better UX.

Comment: @JeremyRea Maybe you misunderstood my question. My app one have ONE story(one button to see one story). If you press it, you can see pictures just like Snapchat, and tap to go to the next one. If the users leave the app, I want it to be able to continue where he left off, instead of starting all over again. I am not using a `UITableView`, the images is displayed in a `UIImageView`.

Comment: In that case, you just need to save the objID of the current picture each time the user taps to see the next one and then start your loop from that ID each time. For the first launch, you should check to see if the value stored in nsuserdefaults is nil and if so set it to the first picture in the sequence.

Comment: @RoduckNickes Sorry about that. In that case, I'd add to Chris' original answer that your PFObject can have a boolean field `viewed` (or something similar) and add `viewed == false` to your query. Each time the post is presented or that the user taps it to go to the next one, you can set the `viewed` property to true. That way, the next time the app opens and you query your posts, you'll only get the ones that haven't been seen yet.

Comment: Only problem is that the app does not store users(does not have users), so there is no way to identify the current "user".

Comment: That seems like a different question. Assuming one user per device is pretty standard for an iOS app.

Comment: @RoduckNickes Are your ID's incremental (i.e. 1, 2, 3 ...) or random (i.e. UUID)? If they are random, since your PFObject already has a createdAt field, you can store on the user's device the date of the post each time he sees one and add to your query the condition that createdAt be bigger than the stored date on the device. If your ID's follow a sequence, you can do the same thing but by storing the last seen id locally instead of a date.

Comment: @Chris I'm guessing that it's still one user per device, but that the queries are done to a server who's database doesn't have the notion of users, so there wouldn't be a way of persisting the viewed status of each individual "user" unless caching all the posts locally which would take up too much room?

Comment: @JeremyRea Correct. Query's are done to a server who's database doesn't have the users..

Comment: @RoduckNickes Do you think that storing the most recent date locally like mentioned above will work for you?

Comment: @JeremyRea I'm not sure. FYI: I am using Parse database to store the images.